# Returning the highest of two NoneTypes

Tags: python, list

we are trying to find out how to compare the values of two nontypes to find the highest scoring dice, but every time we run the code it displays Typeerror: unorderable types: Nonetype() > Nonetype()

```
def compareresult():
    if giveresult(dice) > giveresult(newdice):
        print(giveresult(dice))

    elif giveresult(newdice) > giveresult(dice):
        print(giveresult(newdice))
    return dice, newdice
```

`giveresult` is:

```
def giveresult(tempDice):
    if fiveofakind(tempDice) is True:
        tempScore = int(50)
        print(tempScore)
    if fiveofakind(tempDice) is False:
        tempScore = int(0)
        print(tempScore)
```

Comment: You can't. You are trying to compare `None` to `None`, because `giveresult` doesn't return anything else. You need to fix your `giveresult()` function to *return* a value.

Comment: Show us the definition of `giveresult()`.

Comment: how does one do that?

Comment: def giveResult(tempDice):
     if fiveofakind(tempDice) is True:
          tempScore = int(50)
          print(tempScore)
     if fiveofakind(tempDice) is False:
           tempScore = int(0)
           print(tempScore)

Comment: **Edit the question**. Code (particularly Python, where whitespace is part of the syntax) is unreadable in comments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: but `if None > None:` executes without issue (python 2.7, though)

Comment: @njzk2 that and the `print` suggests the OP is using 3.x

Comment: @njzk2: not on Python 3 it doesn't. In Python 2 almost everything can be ordered, but this caused too many types of problems. At least the OP here got an error now because the functions returned unexpected `None` values rather than whatever they were supposed to produce.

Comment: btw I am using python 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `giveresult()` function is not *returning* anything, so the default `None` is returned. Printing is not the same thing; you are writing text to the terminal, not returning and the caller cannot use text written to a terminal.

Replace `print()` with `return`:

```
def giveResult(tempDice):
    if fiveofakind(tempDice):
        return 10
    else:
        return 0
```

I also simplified your function; there is no need to test for `is True`; `if` already tests if the result of `fiveofakind()` is true or not. And because you already tested for `fiveofakind()`, all you need to do is use `else` to pick the other case.

Next, avoid calling `giveResult` more than per dice, and again, *return* the result from your function:

```
def compareresult():
    dice_result = giveResult(dice)
    newdice_result = giveResult(newdice)
    if dice_result > newdice_result
        return dice_result

    elif newdice_result > dice_result:
        return newdice_result

    return dice, newdice
```

If you must return the greater result, just use the [`max()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
def compareresult():
    dice_result = giveResult(dice)
    newdice_result = giveResult(newdice)
    return max(dice_result, newdice_result)
```